# How to get click eventargs when setting onclick from server-side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, eventargs

I'm  trying to open a div like a popup, but having it centered at the spot where the mouse was when it triggered the onclick event.  In order to get the mouse position, I've been following this example

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $("#special").click(function(e){
      $('#status2').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
   }); 
})
```

in that example, the click function is set client-side.  However, in my scenario, I am going to set the onclick function server-side to many dynamically created objects.  I will also be adding an argument to my function that will be unique to each object created.

The problem I'm facing is that I can't seem to get the eventargs ("e") when I set the onclick event NOT using JQuery.

Ultimately, a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve would look something like this:

```
<div id="divSubscription" style="display: none; height: 0px; width: 0px; position: absolute;">some content</div>     
<input type="button" id="btnOpenPopup" value="Open" onclick='openPopup(8, e)' />

    function openPopup(subID, e) {
        var x = e.pageX;
        var y = e.pageY;
        $("#divSubscription").css("top", y);
        $("#divSubscription").css("left", x);
        $("#divSubscription").css("display", "block");
        $("#divSubscription").animate({ height: "400px", width: "400px" }, 300, "swing");

        $("#divSubscriptionContent").html(subID);
    }
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, because it has no idea what "e" is.  Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class names instead of ids and a data-id attribute to store button specific data (i.e. subID):

CSS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $(".special").click(function(e){
      var subID = $(this).attr('data-id'); 
      $("#divSubscriptionContent").html(subID);
   }); 
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="divSubscription">some content</div>
<input class="special" data-id="8" type="button" id="btnOpenPopup" value="Open" />
```

Comment: what about the other argument I need to assign?  In this case, the subscriptionID

edit: that looks promising. thank you

Comment: just edited my answer to include the subscription ID to the button (as `data-id`)

Comment: awesome, works perfectly.  I had thought about doing it by class, but I was unaware of the data-id attribute. Thanks again!

Comment: To be a little bit clearer, naming it `data-id` is just one possibility.  Technically you could name it `data-sub-id` or anything else that starts with `data-`

Comment: apparently it doesn't even need to start with "data-" i just tried naming the attribute "asdfasdfasdf" and it worked!  Good to know!

Comment: That is correct, but not recommended.  the `data-` attribute was introduced to allow for custom attributes, without interfering with other attributes.

Answer (score -1):

Try using delegated events, where #BUTTON_ANCESTOR is the element that contains your buttons:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $("#BUTTON_ANCESTOR").on('click', 'input[type=button]', (function(e){
           $('#status2').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
      }); 
 })
```

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I think you should remove the onclick and use jquery or some similar framework to attach a click handler and listen for the event.

Simply, with jQuery

```
$('#btnOpenPopup').bind('click', {foo:bar}, openPopup(e));
```

Do this in your bootstrap, or initialization process, and get out of the habit of putting your javascript in the html files. IMHO, you should only ever need one script include.